# Primefaces FileUploadListener not invoking listener method in bean class in wildfly 20 server

Tags: java, primefaces, wildfly

**step 1: XHTML
form enctype**

```
<p:fileUpload id="fileupload_Test" 
                          fileUploadListener="#{CIM.handleFileUpload}" auto="true"
                          fileLimit="1"  label="Select Excel File" mode="advanced" 
                          invalidSizeMessage="File size limit exceeds.Maximum allowable size '#{CIM.xlFileSizeLimit}'MB. FileName: " 
                           sizeLimit="100000"
                          allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls|xlsx)$/"  onstart="PF('import_glasspane').block()" 
                          oncomplete="PF('import_glasspane').unblock()" >
            </p:fileUpload>
```

**step 2:
bean - listener**

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}
```

Note: working fine in wildfly version : 10, primefaces version 6.1.11.

Issue: After migrating wildfly 20, fileupload listener is not invoking.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There are a number of things that can cause the behavior where events are not invoked. From what I can tell, there is nothing wrong with your code  specifically. However, there might be something else on-page that is causing the problem.

Comment: Above code is perfectly invoking the bean method in wildlfy 10 server.
But could not invoke same in wildfly 20 server.

Comment: I gave example with note and exact issue. kindly check @AdamWaldenberg

Comment: Kindly check and update

Comment: If it works with V10 and not V20 I would look into compatibility issues. Maybe there is a problem with JSF 2.3.9 (which WildFly 20 uses) and PrimeFaces 6.1.11 ?

Comment: I have created simple war file project and tested file upload component in wildfly 20 version.
But it does not working. Attached my project URL.

https://github.com/MohanMuthusamy243/sampleJSF/tree/master/JSFSample

Note : FileUploadListener method invoking fine in wildfly 17.0.1 and below version, but not working in 18 and above version.

Comment: Sir kindly check and update @AdamWaldenberg

Comment: As stated before - most likely there is a compatibility issue with your version of PrimeFaces (which  is  over 5 years old at this point) and the newer version of JSF in WildFly. Either update PrimeFaces, or downgrade JSF when deploying in WildFly 18+. Your best bet is probably to upgrade PrimeFaces.